# Firestore rule not working as expected

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have following rule set up on firestore.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /items/{itemid} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner;
    }
  }
}
```

In my Angular service, I am initializing collection as follows:

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private fs: AngularFirestore) {
  this.itemsCollection = this.fs.collection('items', cr => {
    return cr.where('owner', '==', authService.currentUserId);
  });
}
```

Code to *read* items:

```
items() {
  return this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
}
```

Code to *write* item:

```
addItem(item: ItemEntry): Observable<DocumentReference> {
  item.owner = this.authService.currentUserId;
  return Observable.fromPromise(this.itemsCollection.add(item));
}
```

The **read** operation works correctly, but the **write** operation (*addItem*) fails with error

> Missing or insufficient permissions.

Unable to figure out, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the [`resource`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#firestore-resource) variable:

> contains a map of the fields and values stored in a document in
>   `resource.data`.

This means that `resource.data` only contains the data that is already stored on the database.

You should use [`request.resource`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#resource) instead. Because it contains the data being written to the database. Your new rules would look like this:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.owner;
```

Comment: On an update, you should check the existing, not the new data. So just add "or doesn't exist" to the write rule.

Comment: Thanks much, worked like charm. Had to split the rule, though. Original rule for read, new rule for write.   Thanks agian.